# Unexpected token < after angular 2 production build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, deployment

After building my angular 2 app with `ng build -prod` I copied the `dist` folder in my node.js project and modified the base tag to  `<base href="/app/">`

Now when I try open in the browser I receive following errors:

> polyfills.aa13f03….bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   < vendor.3dc323c….bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   main.ba0828d….bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

the node.js route:

```
router.route('/app/*').get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('app/index.html', {root: __dirname })
});
```

Angular Version: 5.1.0
Angular Cli Version: 1.0.1

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it with a apache server, there it works fine

Comment: Have you found any workaround for running on nodejs server?

Comment: No not really, i solved it in another way but I had a similar problem recently, try something like that: app.use('/doc', express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

Comment: So nice to hear from you. I was able to solve the issue using `express.static`