# 'Unexpected token <' on every new build of angular production PWA until site refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-web-app-service, progressive-web-apps

I know there are some similar questions like so [unexpected token after angular 2 production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803182/unexpected-token-after-angular-2-production-build) but it doesnt actually answer my question.

Basically I have an angular app and its a PWA, now everytime I do a new production build the first time I visit the site I get an error like so

[image]

and then as soon as I refresh the page, the site works as normal.

**This happens on any browser/device**

Now my suspicion is that every time the app is updated, the main bundled js file changes, and the PWA has cached the old one and the app is still trying to use the new one.

My Project structure is as follows

I have a root module that lazy loads the other modules now the first module that gets loaded is my account module so the user can log in

this is my **root-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/account/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: 'account/account.module#AccountModule',
        data: { preload: true }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class RootRoutingModule {
```

}

so technically the first module the user gets to is the account module, but obviously it has to be redirected from the root module.

So what I did was in my root component module I check to see if the Service Worker needs updating like so...

**root.component.ts**

```
@import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker'
...

export class...

constructor(
    private _sw: SwUpdate
) {
    if (this._sw.isEnabled) {
        this._sw.available
            .subscribe(() => {
                this._sw.activateUpdate()
                    .then(() => {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    });
            });
    }
}
```

now this should check to see if there is an update and then just refresh the page.. but it **doesn't work.**

this is my **ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "App",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "!/main*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see I am excluding the `main.js` chunk file which should eliminate this issue... **but it doesn't**

Now when I check the network tab after a new build this is what I get

[image]
*This image was before I excluded the main.js file*

this is what my `main.js` calls look like after I have excluded it from the `ngsw.config`

[image]

I then thought to just try and catch this error using my sentry error handler like so..

```
export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: any): void {
    console.log('error', err);
    if (err.toLowerCase().includes('token <')) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    } else {
        Raven.captureException(err);
    }
  }
}
```

but this isn't working, I am getting the error in sentry but the app is not reloading??

Now I have done some testing, If you visit the site after a fresh build on private mode you will never get the error, it only seems to happen if you have visited the site before, which is what makes me think its a caching issue

My Application is hosted on **Azure** and my application is using **Angular 7.27**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By any chance are you using a base href other than “/“?
I vaguely remember dealing with a similar problem when hosting on github pages and using a base href for the repo name. If that is the case I can look at my commit history and see if I can remember how I fixed it.

Comment: No definitely using '/' as my base href

Comment: Are you getting an error in IE or in all the browser?

Comment: @BhargilJoshi all browsers

Comment: @smokey Dawson  have you fixed this issue. Please  let me know if any fix would be greatly appreciated. I m seriously looking for fix

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is caused by the installed `ServiceWorker`, which is the one that interferes and **caches** all responses, including the ones that you have just updated.

More information about service workers: MDN - Using Service workers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

That is why `window.location.reload()` does not work, because it does make a new request **but this request is hijacked** by the installed `ServiceWorker` and instead of letting the real request go through to the real server and fetch the real response (updated main.js and assets), it just returns back to your app a cached response, which is the old main.js and not the updated one and that is why it fails.

More specifically the `ServiceWorker` is caching the `main.js` and other assets, which are generated each time you change your code. Main.js when loaded in turn it lazy-loads (makes an http request to) other chunks of your application (e.g. the 5.xxxxx.js).

When you do make a change in your code, and even though all your chunks gets updated, including `main.js` and the `5.xxxxxx.js` chunk, the browser is still running the older `main.js`. This older `main.js` has a reference to the older pair of `5.xxxxxx.js` which no longer exists. At this point if you do a reload() programatically, the installed `ServiceWorker` responds with the older cached `main.js` which tries in turn to lazy-load the older version of `5.xxxxx.js` from the server which does not exist and therefore gets a response of an 404 html error. Hence the `'<'` token exception (it's actually the first character of the  tag of the 404 error page).

This is evident from the **network panel screenshot**. If you examine the screenshot you will see that the `main.js` and all other assets are delivered from `(from service worker)`, which means that those are the cached older versions and are different from the actual updated files that now exist in your web server.

To fix this issue, the `ServiceWorker` must be configured to **not cache** the `main.js` and instead always let this request to go through to the real server in order to fetch any updated version of `main.js` that in turn will lazy-load the updated `5.xxxx.js` chunk that now actually exist in the web server.

Here is how you can configure the `ngsw-config.json` of `ServiceWorker` to specifically **not cache** the `main.js` file (assuming it is of the pattern `main.xxxxxxx.js`) in order to fix this issue:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "App",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "/!main*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

run `ng build --prod` to rebuild your app and test it.

**UPDATE:**

To make sure that this is not a browser caching issue, pass `true` as the first argument to the window.location.reload() method. This instructs the reload to be executed without cached assets by the browser:

**root.component.ts**

```
                    .then(() => {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    });
```

**UPDATE 2:**

According to the documentation of Angular, the Service Worker that is installed already on browsers of clients is cached. If you update the Service Worker code (like you did recently), then the new Service Worker code must be updated in all the browsers of the clients that have it already installed. Angular documentation states that there is a periodic check, but it doesn't specify it, that will check if the Service Worker itself needs an update and will do it.
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#service-worker-updates

Perhaps, the manefistation of the issue only in the production and not in development or with a Private Browser mode (clean browser slate with no SW installed), seems that this is the case.

To verify this, you should compare the existing browser's SW that is running on the page using the developer tools of Chrome, with the updated SW code that should be installed. If they are different then it means that it hasn't been updated yet and that's what's causing the issue.

You can do this using a chrome browser that exhibits this issue and by going to **Chrome Dev tools -> Application Tab -> Service Workers (in the top of left panel)** and there will be the SW that is registered in the browser. Click the Source link and it will open up the actual Code of the SW. Compare the code line by line (or use a diff utility) with the updated SW code that should be running.

Comment: This sounds like exactly my problem

Comment: If you look at my question it shows you my `ngsw-config.json` file which basically caches all `.css` and `.js`

Comment: OK, although I'm not familiar with the `ngsw-config.json` format, I'll look it up and see if we can bypass the caching of the main.js and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks that would be great!

Comment: OK I think I got it right. I updated my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: So I have implemented this, and built my project - now since it was a small change I don't think it would of happened, but it didnt happen this time. But when I check the network it still says that the .main file is being recieved from the service worker??

Comment: Okay So, I have deployed a few times and it has seemed to stop happening.. but in saying that I haven't pushed anything major - so could just not be happening. Unfortunately the issue is one of those, you think its fixed until it happens again type deal... so for now I will mark this as correct you give you the bounty.. If it happens again in the future obviously I will mark as incorrect and up the bounty further. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you! Don't worry though, because the issue is definitely fixed. Although the main.js file is indeed still served by the service worker, it no longer caches it but instead each time it fetches the file from the web server and therefore it always responds back with the updated one. This is because we have explicitly configured the WS (ngsw-config) to never cache the main.xxxxx.js.

Comment: Unfortunately, just pushed a major build and the issue still occurred :(

Comment: What a bummer. Well I noticed one more thing that you can change and I updated my answer, check it out and let me know. 

**IF** however, this still doesn't make it work, then we will have to dig even deeper, are you willing to share (privately) the production site to check it out myself too?

Comment: I have already added true to `window.location.reload()` in my root component when it checks for a new version of  a pwa, I will also add it to my errorHandler and see if that helps

Comment: Are you sure that the WS code of the production host, that is being served to the clients has been also updated? Furthermore, what about those clients that already have installed an older version of the WS on their browsers, did those WS got updated with the new WS code? 

I think this is where the cause of this is located.

Comment: This sounds like it could be the culprit, however when I vist my app in a new browser in private mode, the main.js still seems to be taken from the service worker in the network panel

Comment: I may seem strange but this is how it is supposed to be. It always requests the mainxxxx.js from the SW, because that is the whole point, to enable the SW to act upon that request (give a cached response or download the updated one and give it). The difference with the new SW configuration/code is that the SW will no longer cache mainxxxxx.js and it will always fetch the updated one to give to the app. 

So did this work for you?

Comment: I have not had a chance to test it properly, I awarded you the 200 because you've been so helpful, I will let you know how it goes

Comment: well thank you very much about that. I am interested in seeing this getting solved as it seems that more and more people will face similar situations as SWs become more used.

Comment: I think the solution might be to not cache index.html as index.html tells the browser to load main.xxxxx.js and where the trouble starts from main.xxxx.js tells to load 5.yyyy.js. If we end up not caching main.xxxx.js, index.html is still going to try to serve the older version and we would have the same problem of it not being present on the server

Comment: @smokey Dawson  have you fixed this issue. Please  let me know if any fix would be greatly appreciated. I m seriously looking for fix

Answer (score 5):

Double check your cache headers. Chrome doesn't always listen to no-cache. If you've visited the site recently chrome will load index.html from cache. Causing the error.

We've changed our index.html to no-store and that seemed to solve the issue. 
https://gertjans.home.xs4all.nl/javascript/cache-control.html

Comment: Is adding this `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-STORE">` enough to solve the issue?

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens for me when the requested resource returns 404 and instead of requested JS file you receive your index.html which has tags hence '<' token. Could it somehow be the case? Say you have versioning on your scripts and rebuild invalidates old URLs or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert to angular problem. The best I can do is help you break down the problem, help you debug.

1. If you just want the error go away (and you have control over the server that serves your `index.html`), I'm pretty sure it can solved by setting these *http response headers* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/3617380)):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

2. However, such setup more or less beats the point of PWA in the first place. PWA allow users to use your site even offline, they must be able to get to `index.html` first, so `index.html` has to be cached.
3. Caching `index.html` is the right thing to do. It's likely your cache-control setting for your old `.js` and other assets has some problems. I'm not sure which part goes wrong, but the expected behavior is: these assets should be cached just like `index.html`, 404 should never happen in first place since browser should read from local cache.
4. One thing you can do to quickly "cover up" the problem, is simply keep all the old assets of previous version on server too. This way, cached `index.html` ref to old assets, they remain accessible, no 404 thus no "unexpected token <".
5. Now I would suggest you try point 4 first, to verify my theory at point 3 is correct. Also check if `SwUpdate` works properly. Ideally, you should see following:

   1. you publish newer version of code
   2. you visit the site, should see cached older version
   3. after older version of app is loaded, `SwUpdate` automatically refreshes the page for you and load the newer version.

To sum up, my theory is things go wrong at point 3. Older assets should be correctly cached, using proper http cache-control headers (or angular service worker has other way of doing same things? I'm not familiar with that part). If you cannot figure it out, then just keep the old assets accessible on server.

Comment: I will try no. 3 and get back to you

Comment: Hmm still happening even with the files still being on the server, the issue seems to be related to routing

Comment: @SmokeyDawson oh, so the assumption that '<' is from a 404 is wrong? Have you look into the network panel and see what indeed is the response? You never revealed that piece of info before.

Comment: I've just updated my question with a screenshot of my network panel, as you will see nothing actually fails and all my scripts are coming from the service worker - this seems to be an Angular related problem

Comment: @SmokeyDawson can I see the app live online somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately you cant

Comment: I'm wondering if just removing the cache of the .js files would be a quick fix for now.. my application cant be run offline anyway

Comment: I don't have deep understanding of how PWA works. Run out of idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error when **lazy loading modules**.

It was an Angular / Iconic PWA and was related to a missing import:

```
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
```

Also see:

- [Angular 2. Error: Loading chunk failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034039/angular-2-error-loading-chunk-failed)
- [How to overcome loading chunk failed with Angular lazy loaded modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198268/how-to-overcome-loading-chunk-failed-with-angular-lazy-loaded-modules)

Comment: Yes.. I have lazy loaded modules.. do you have a solution?

Comment: A FeatureModule was missing an import statement for the SharedModule.

The 'Unexpected token' was the first character in the host file (index.html).

Comment: Would this not happen everytime you load your project though?

Comment: Just checked my notes and it seems I tried a few options including: --vendor-chunk=false

- https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-deep-deep-deep-deep-deep-dive-into-the-angular-compiler-5379171ffb7a
- https://medium.com/@kudochien/a-react-webpack-optimization-case-27da392fb3ec
- https://medium.com/@armno/til-analyzing-angular-apps-bundle-size-with-sourcemaps-explorer-f688e8a2386c

Comment: What happens if you clear your browser cache before you visit your updated site?

Comment: Works every time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191828/discussion-between-robinyo-and-smokey-dawson).

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for this issue. For get https://angular.io/cli/build

get your app `angular.json` file. And change outputHashing value all to media

```
           "architect": {
                "build": {
                    ...
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            ...
                            "outputHashing": "media", // "all"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does this do exactly

Comment: @SmokeyDawson It's changed the js files name `1.GUID.js` to `1.js`