# vue-router history mode on mac (localhost) throwing error on direct access

Tags: javascript, macos, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I'm testing out vue-router's history mode on localhost development, and I'm getting an error when I try directly access the URL: `http://localhost:8080/map/2`. When I get to the URL via a `$router.push` of some kind, it behaves correctly. I'm wondering what may be causing this issue.

router/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Router from "vue-router"

const PublicMap = () => import("@/components/PublicMap/index.vue")

Vue.use(Router)

var routes = [
    {
        component: PublicMap,
        name: "map",
        path: "/map/:_id",
    },
]

export default new Router({
    routes,
    mode:
        "history"
})
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: By "directly access", does that mean you entered the URL manually into the address bar? Also can you please post the `PublicMap` component here.

Comment: This should be more related to your server configuration. You should make it always return your index.html

Comment: @Slim yeah, I'm not sure which part of Vue does that. I'm using Vue-cli3 and they said don't modify `historyApiFallback`

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: @MattOestreich that is the full error. Nothing on the terminal either.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that code. The syntaxerror should be from index.vue.

Comment: is your app a PWA? maybe this is causing the error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155359/unexpected-token-on-every-new-build-of-angular-production-pwa-until-site-ref, see the answers on this post

Comment: that might have been the case tbh. I started with PWA but then dropped it because it was causing some issues. Maybe there was some remnant problem

Comment: Because of you miss a hash sign in the url: http://localhost:8080/#/map/2

Answer (score 2):

When you receive an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, it usually means your transpiler has hit an element tag '<' in a file it is not set up to transpile.

When using Vue, this is usually a `<script>` tag in a `xyz.vue` single file component library.

If you used PWA, a file or setting might be cached.  I would first try a different browser that has not visited the page to see if it is a caching issue.  If it works in a different browser, try a `hard refresh`, or unregister the service worker for page's web app.

If it fails in another browser, I would look into your webpack and/or vue config files.

[image]

Comment: it only occurs during history mode. Hash mode works perfectly fine.

Comment: What are you using to serve the url?

Comment: just localhost. The documentation said that it should work in both hash and history mode without any modifications.

Comment: But are you using the vue-cli server, webpack-dev-server, etc.  What application is serving your content?  You can't use history mode by just opening a file on your drive.  There needs to be a fallback URL.

Comment: just using vue-cli3, and running `npm start`. So basically, the history routing works, if I get redirected through a `RouterLink` html tag, but doesn't work if it directly access it (i.e. punch it via the url bar)

Comment: yeah, some issue probably messed up with I decided to remove pwa since I couldn't figure out why it was loading vue's default favicon instead of my custom one. Ah well, I switched to nuxt and it just feels a lot saner instead of figuring out vue-cli3's new plugin stuff.